# How to calculate tunneling current between two metals separated by a dielectric?

Tags: electric-current, quantum-tunneling

If I have two metallic electrodes (e.g. Al, Cr) separated by a dielectric (ε, d; e.g. SiO2), how can I calculate the tunneling current as a function of applied voltage?

Comment: It is not possible to say, until you specify the metal.   The electron wavefunction (and the density of electrons) would, in general, depend on the nature of the metal surface (and be dissimilar to the bulk material).  The general expectation, though, would be exponential decaying function of 'd'.

Comment: @Whit3rd updated question